# How to use javascript to insert tags in tables

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, insert

I'm trying to find a way to insert html element tags into a table structure. There are often multiple tables in an html page so I dynamically create and insert an ID for each table which works fine. However, when I try to insert specific html elements into the different portions of the table I get nothing but errors or the table never gets updated.

I'm a technical writer experimenting with javascript and the authoring tool I use doesn't allow for thead and tbody tags, so when I come across a table in an html page in my document that doesn't have this structure, I need to add it. Afterwards, I dynamically implement visual elements into the table to make it easier to find information.

This all works fine on tables that already have the thead structure so I need a way to get this structure into tables that don't have it.

Here's a before and after view of what I'm trying to do:

Before:

```
    <table class="TableHeadingOnTop" style="border-collapse: separate" 
                                             cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <tr class="t1Row">
            <td class="t1Col"><p class="MoreList"><a 
             href="DefaultProbeComponents.htm">DefaultProbeComponents</a></p></td>
            <td class="t2Col"><p class="MoreList"><a href="ProbeQualVisionOpticsCalFocusLatencyDuration1.htm">ProbeQualVisionOpticsCalFocusLatencyDuration1</a></p></td>
            <td class="last"><p class="MoreList"><a 
            href="VFTScan_LSPX1C_Speed1.htm">VFTScan_LSPX1C_Speed1</a></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="t2Row">
            td class="t1Col"><p class="MoreList"><a href="DefMode.htm">DefMode</a></p></td>
            <td class="t2Col"><p class="MoreList"><a href="ProbeQualVisionOpticsCalFocusLatencyDuration2.htm">ProbeQualVisionOpticsCalFocusLatencyDuration2</a></p></td>
            <td class="last"><p class="MoreList"><a 
            href="VFTScan_LSPX1C_Speed2.htm">VFTScan_LSPX1C_Speed2</a></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="t1Row">
            <td class="t1Col"><p class="MoreList"><a 
            href="DefMoveSpeed.htm">DefMoveSpeed</a></p></td>
            <td class="t2Col"><p class="MoreList"><a            href="ProbeQualVisionOpticsCalFocusLatencyEnabled.htm">ProbeQualVisionOpticsCalFocusLatencyEnabled</a></p></td>
            <td class="last"><p class="MoreList"><a 
            href="VFTScan_LSPX1H_Acceleration1.htm">VFTScan_LSPX1H_Acceleration1</a></p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

After - here, you can see the thead & /thead and tbody & /tbody structure:

```
<table class="TableHeadingOnTop" style="border-collapse: separate" 
                                             cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><p>&#160;</p></th>
            <th><p>&#160;</p></th>
            <th><p>&#160;</p></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="t1Row">
            <td class="t1Col"><p class="MoreList"><a 
             href="DefaultProbeComponents.htm">DefaultProbeComponents</a></p></td>
            <td class="t2Col"><p class="MoreList"><a 
             href="ProbeQualVisionOpticsCalFocusLatencyDuration1.htm">ProbeQualVisionOpticsCalFocusLatencyDuration1</a></p></td>
            <td class="last"><p class="MoreList"><a 
             href="VFTScan_LSPX1C_Speed1.htm">VFTScan_LSPX1C_Speed1</a></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="t2Row">
            <td class="t1Col"><p class="MoreList"><a 
             href="DefMode.htm">DefMode</a></p></td>
            <td class="t2Col"><p class="MoreList"><a 
             href="ProbeQualVisionOpticsCalFocusLatencyDuration2.htm">ProbeQualVisionOpticsCalFocusLatencyDuration2</a></p></td>
            <td class="last"><p class="MoreList"><a 
             href="VFTScan_LSPX1C_Speed2.htm">VFTScan_LSPX1C_Speed2</a></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="t1Row">
            <td class="t1Col"><p class="MoreList"><a 
             href="DefMoveSpeed.htm">DefMoveSpeed</a></p></td>
            <td class="t2Col"><p class="MoreList"><a 
             href="ProbeQualVisionOpticsCalFocusLatencyEnabled.htm">ProbeQualVisionOpticsCalFocusLatencyEnabled</a></p></td>
            <td class="last"><p class="MoreList"><a 
             href="VFTScan_LSPX1H_Acceleration1.htm">VFTScan_LSPX1H_Acceleration1</a></p></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please let me know if there's a way to do this - thanks!

Here's a clarification of the challenge I'm facing:

````
// In this function, I want to insert the thead structure
// and the opening and closing tbody tags...
// this function receives the value of the number of
// columns in the table and the table's ID name...
function createtheadstruct(colcount, id_name_new){
    var table = document.getElementById(id_name_new);
    var header = table.createTHead();
    var row = header.insertRow(0);
    var theadcntr = colcount-1;
    var cell
    
    // Here I'm inserting the thead data rows (td)
    // based on the column counter (theadcntr)
    for (var i=0; i<=theadcntr; i++) {
        cell = row.insertCell(i);
        cell.innerHTML = "$#160;";
    }
    
    //After the thead structure is created, I want to insert the opening tbody tag.
    //Since the rows and cells of table's body are already there, I want to insert
    //the opening tbody tag right after the closing thead tag (/thead) and then the
    //closing tbody tag (/tbody) before the closing table tag (/table)
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can call the `insertRow()` method on a Table DOM element, followed by calls to the `insertCell()` method as shown below to dynamically add tags to your table with JavaScript.

Try this on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/zrgm3bsj/1/), it seems to work just fine for me!

```js
// First create a table to be used as an example.
const table = document.getElementById('test-table-1')
const head = document.createElement('thead')

// Create 3 th tags for an example.

const th1 = document.createElement('th')
th1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Test Header 1'))

const th2 = document.createElement('th')
th2.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Test Header 2'))

const th3 = document.createElement('th')
th3.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Test Header 3'))

// Add the th tags to the thead
head.appendChild(th1)
head.appendChild(th2)
head.appendChild(th3)

// Give the table the thead.
table.appendChild(head)

// Now we have a table to work with.

// Create a tbody.
const tbody = document.createElement('tbody')

// Add a couple of rows.
const tr1 = tbody.insertRow()
const tr2 = tbody.insertRow()

// Add td tags to to rows.
for (let tr of [tr1, tr2]) {
    for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {
    const td = tr.insertCell(i)
    td.innerText = 'foo'+i
  }
}

// Add the tbody to the table.
table.appendChild(tbody)
```

```html
<table id="test-table-1"></table>
```

Comment: Hi Kameron - Thank you for the response, but I'm working with an already existing table with td rows already created. Please see my Before/After table structures in my original post. Is there a way to create and insert the opening and closing tbody tags in their correct positions in an already existing table? I need a way to insert the opening tbody tag after the closing thead tag and the closing tbody tag before the closing table tag.

Comment: Hi Kameron - In response to your statement that I'm asking for someone to do my work, that was never my intent. I spent many hours and many days working on my own to try and figure out the logic for the multiple ways a table in html could be coded and then work out how to implement a way to insert the thead and tbody tags appropriately. Many of the html pages have multiple tables in them and not all are coded exactly the same. Some have no headings, some have headings with the cells coded as td, some with th. I'm rather new to StackOverflow so I wasn't aware of how important upvoting is.

Comment: Also, none of the tables I come across have ID's applied to them which I have to inject a unique ID into them so I can then process them using DataTables for users to more easily locate information through searches, etc. I apologize if you feel I was taking advantage of you but I thought this was a community where I could reach out for help - and only help - to try and resolve coding issues. I have upvoted you - thanks.